# How to validate a phone number in this format

Tags: javascript, regex

So in my check phone number function, I have:
the variable pn represents the textfield where the client inputs the phone number.

The desired format is: 000-0000 (obviously not only zeroes, but any digit 0-9).

How can I use regex to validate that it is in the desired format, and give an alert if it isn't? This is what i have

```
var pn = document.getElementById('ph').value;
//var vd = pn.search?

//if(not valid, alert("Not a valid number!");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `The desired format is: 000-0000`

Then following regex should work:

```
/^\d{3}-\d{4}$/
```

**TEST:**

```
re = /^\d{3}-\d{4}$/;

re.test('123-4567'); // true
re.test('123-45678'); // false
```

Comment: so will the search return a 0 if its valid

Comment: How would I set up the If statement telling the compiler to send an alert if its not valid?

Comment: You can write: `if (!re.test('123-4567')) alert ("invalid phone");`

Comment: Okay sweet it works, now how can I tell it to check the value of the input textbox that call 'pn' ? Because thats where the phone number will be going in.